# STS Unable to create java virtual machine

Tags: eclipse, jvm

In my STS installation, I tried to upgrade Xmx1024 to Xmx4096. My computer computer has 8GB installed memory. But it keeps giving me an error message - "could not create java virtual machine" and exits with code 1. What could possibly be the problem and what should I do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's it: you're running a 32 bit JVM. I think you can't have more than 3GiB (or maybe 2GiB, I read *by there*) in a 32 bit JVM.

Can you try running a 64 bit JVM?

---

As they say in [this article](http://javahowto.blogspot.com.ar/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html), you seem to be missing the unit.

Don't you want to write `Xmx4096m`?

Comment: If you see the screen shot, eclipse automatically adds Xmx4096m

Comment: @SajanChandran now I see the screenshot. I edited the answer - can it be true?